# Spring Boot 3 and Thymeleaf - object not rendering in the form

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-thymeleaf

This is my controller method:

```
   // show update form
@RequestMapping(value="/updateprep/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showUpdateUserForm(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("updateJob", repository.findById(id).orElseThrow());

    return "updatejob";

}
```

And this is the form tag of the view:

```
<form th:object="${updateJob}" th:action="@{/savejob}" method="post" enctype=                                                   "multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
...
```

Have I made a stupid error, as my page is rendered with the literal value of the template placeholder, e.g.
`${updateJob.place}`?

Comment: What does the rest of your form look like. Have you used `th:field` properly?

Comment: The answer is no. I did the likes of `value="${updateJob.notes}"` I suspect we're edging towards the "stupid error" category :)

Comment: Well not sure if it is the "stupid error" category but it is in the "Error between chair and keyboard" category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when the output is like the exact value you put in you are probably using `value="${updateJob.place}"`. Which will do just that set the value to the literal string `${updateJob.place}`.

You should either use `th:value` instead of `value` but as you want to do binding you problably should use `th:field` instead.

```
<input type="text" th:field="*{place}">
```

Which will automatically generate a `value`, `name` etc. as well and integrate with Spring.

Comment: Thanks. What about when the target is not an attribute, but the actual *content* of an element, e.g. `<textarea>?`?

Comment: You can uyse the same on a textarea.